# Gatsby - Uncaught TypeError - Context/build problem

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, gatsby

I was developing my application in Gatsby and got stuck. Everything is working fine with "gatsby develop", but when I run "gatsby build" I get an error:

```
"WebpackError: TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'cursorStyles' of 'Object(...)(...)' as it is undefined."
```

And yeah, cursorStyles are defined in the context, so everything should work perfectly or I am missing something. Tried to clean cache, but still the error occurs, which is very weird cuz didn't have any problems to work on this project locally.

EDIT - yes, I wrapped the gatsby application with the Global Provider as you can see below. I just don't understand why the build doesn't work, when I clearly have the access to the context... ;/

**gatsby-browser.js**

```
import React from "react"
import { GlobalProvider } from "./src/context/globalContext"

export const wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => {
  return <GlobalProvider>{element}</GlobalProvider>
}
```

**Context - values are defined in global provider const**

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer, useContext } from "react"

//Define Context
const GlobalStateContext = createContext()
const GlobalDispatchContext = createContext()


//Reducer
const globalReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case "TOGGLE_THEME": {
        return {
          ...state,
          currentTheme: action.theme,
        }
      }
      case "CURSOR_TYPE": {
        return {
          ...state,
          cursorType: action.cursorType,
        }
      }
      default: {
        throw new Error(`Unhandled action type: ${action.type}`)
      }
    }
  }



  export const GlobalProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(globalReducer, {
      currentTheme: "dark",
      cursorType: false,
      cursorStyles: ["pointer", "hovered", "locked", "white"],
    })

    return (
        <GlobalDispatchContext.Provider value={dispatch}>
          <GlobalStateContext.Provider value={state}>
            {children}
          </GlobalStateContext.Provider>
        </GlobalDispatchContext.Provider>
      )
}

//custom hooks for when we want to use our global state
export const useGlobalStateContext = () => useContext(GlobalStateContext)

export const useGlobalDispatchContext = () => useContext(GlobalDispatchContext)
```

**Layout.js - problem occurs when destructuring and using my custom hook**

```
import React, {useState} from "react"
import PropTypes from "prop-types"
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from "gatsby"

import { createGlobalStyle, ThemeProvider } from "styled-components"
import { normalize } from "styled-normalize"

import Header from './header'
import Cursor from './customCursor'
import Navigation from './navigation'

import { useGlobalStateContext, useGlobalDispatchContext } from '../context/globalContext'


const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  const { cursorStyles, currentTheme } = useGlobalStateContext()
  const dispatch = useGlobalDispatchContext()
  const data = useStaticQuery(graphql`
    query SiteTitleQuery {
      site {
        siteMetadata {
          title
        }
      }
    }
  `)

  const darkTheme = {
    background: '#000',
    text:'#fff',
    red: '#ea291e'
  }

  const lightTheme = {
    background: '#fff',
    text:'#000',
    red: '#ea291e'
  }

  const onCursor = cursorType => {
    cursorType = (cursorStyles.includes(cursorType) && cursorType || false)
    dispatch({ type: "CURSOR_TYPE", cursorType: cursorType})
  }

  const [toggleMenu, setToggleMenu] = useState(false)

  return(
    <ThemeProvider theme={currentTheme === "dark" ? darkTheme : lightTheme}>
    <GlobalStyle/>
    <Cursor toggleMenu={toggleMenu} />
    <Header onCursor={onCursor} toggleMenu={toggleMenu} setToggleMenu={setToggleMenu} />
    <Navigation onCursor={onCursor} toggleMenu={toggleMenu} setToggleMenu={setToggleMenu} />
    <main>{children}</main>
    {console.log(currentTheme)}
    </ThemeProvider>
  ) 
  
  
}

Layout.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.node.isRequired,
}

export default Layout
```

Comment: update : tried to add double brackets in the value in context - nothing. Console.log in layout.js shows that the value is not undefined. First I wrapped gatsby-browser, but later I was trying to wrap also other components to see if that's the problem - but still nothing... The error tends to occur also in other components, but it's all about this destructuring which is allegedly undefined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I solved it! I don't know why, but I guess it's just Gatsby who works in a mysterious way. I duplicated my code from gatsby-browser, and put exactly the same thing into the gatsby-ssr file and... surprisingly the weird errors about "object undefined" disappeared.

Unfortunately, due to the fact that gatsby build in that case works similar to the next.js' server-side rendering, I had to fix my code in different places - e.g "window" properties had to be rendered conditionally - but duplicating gatsby-browser's code to the gatsby-ssr fixed the building problem! So as I thought, it wasn't a problem with my code, but rather a problem with gatsby's config.

Comment: Damn! Thanks a lot for this!
Probably makes sense wrapping the root element with the context provider, for server side renders as well, but, this type of code duplication shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Very strange. This problem happens only in production. Duplicating the code from gatsby-browser inside gatsby-ssr - really solves it!

```
import React from 'react';
import CartProvider from './src/components/CartProvider';
export const wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => (
  <CartProvider>{element}</CartProvider>
);
```